# Why are these calculus expressions equivalent?

Tags: calculus

Why are these two expressions equivalent?

$e^{-t^2}[\frac{dy}{dt}-2ty] = e^{-t^2}bt$

$\frac{d}{dt}e^{-t^2}y=e^{-t^2}bt $

I realize that $  \frac{d}{dt}e^{-t^2}=-2te^{-t^2} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Product Rule is being used. The derivative of the product $e^{-t^2}y$ is equal to $e^{-t^2}\frac{dy}{dt}+(-2te^{-t^2})y$.

Now take the common factor $e^{-t^2}$ "out" and we get $e^{-t^2}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}-2t\right)$.

Comment: Thank you. I knew there must be a simple explanation.